# WPF ComboBox ItemsSource Binding on Dictionary not working

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, data-binding, itemssource

I'm having trouble with this binding and can't seem to get it working.

xaml

```
<telerik:RadComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding ReminderTimes.Keys}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReminderTime, 
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
/>
```

c#

```
 public Dictionary<string, int> ReminderTimes
 {
     get { return ReminderTimesManager.GetReminderTimes(); }
 }
```

I did put a breakpoint in the properties get and it's not getting hit ever and I have no idea why. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your property "ReminderTimes" only has a getter, make sure you use Mode=OneWay. By default, ItemsSource is a two way binding.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ReminderTimes.Keys, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: If you remove the ".Keys", it should hit the breakpoint at that point. Please let me know.

Comment: Removed .Keys from ReminderTimes.Keys and still no hit

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid error. I found out that the datacontext was being set higher up the tree to a property in my ViewModel.